# Pass additional parameter during Expand event for Kendo Treeview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I've got a Kendo Gridview on the same page as a Treeview.  The Gridview contains rows of clients associated with the current user.  When one of the client rows in the Gridview is selected, I trigger the Treeview to Read the DataSource again (selectedClient is a js variable set when a row in the Gridview is selected):

```
$("#folderTreeView").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.read({ userId: _selectedClient })
```

The rebinding of the TreeView works perfectly. The problem is when the new TreeView has a folder structure with nested folders. When the "expand" icon is clicked, only the id of the item is passed, but I need to pass the currently selected client from the GridView as well (stored in _selectedClient).

So, is there a way to add additional parameters (the userId/_selectedClient in this case) to "whatever" is passed to the server either during the "expand" event or another way?

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult List(int? userId, int? id)
{
 ....
}
```

Razor

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("folderTreeView")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("List", "Folder", new { area = "Portal"           }).Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
        )
    )
    .Events(events => events
        .Expand("onSelect")
        )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this today, it is for a Grid, but I am going to assume it works fine with anything else that uses a DataSource:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.Product>()
.Name("Grid")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")
        .Data("additionalData") // the name of the JavaScript function which will return the additional data
    )
)
.Pageable()
)
<script>
function additionalData() {
    return {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe"
    };
}
</script>
```

Read more here on [The Kendo Docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding#pass-additional-data-to-action-method)...

Answer (score 2):

I finally found it -- 
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/migration/widgets/treeview

**DataSource events** as outlined below...

```
<script>
  function addData(data) {
    return { userId: _selectedClient };
  }
</script>

<div class="demo-section">
  @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("folderTreeView")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Read(read => read
              .Action("List", "Folder", new { area = "Portal" })
              .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
              .Data("addData")
            )
        )
    )
</div>
```

Comment: What parameters does your `Folder` parameter take for this to work? `area`, `firstName`, and `lastName`? I am not getting any additional data when doing this.

Comment: Richie - I'm using an MVC pattern within .net. So, the ".Action" is building a link to hit a specific area, controller, and method within my application ([server.tld]/Portal/Folder/List). The "List" method in my controller will accept 2 parameters in this example: "id" (which is the folder id that Kendo automatically passes) and "userId" which is the additional, custom parameter that I add using the .Data extension (which calls the js function "addData" and reads a global js variable I have defined (_selectedClient). So I am only passing two parameters to the server, id and userId. Help?